# Partial derivative using irregular variables?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find the partial derivative with respect to $M$ for:
$$\frac{d}{dM} \frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{GM}}$$

I know how to solve for a partial derivative, but I'm having trouble because for starters I'm not even sure how many variables I'm working with. I'm not given a value for r so I'm gonna assume that's a variable, so I have $r$, $G$, and $M$ all as variables. That being said, I've tried taking the derivative in both cases where $r$ is and isn't a variable.

Comment: the period T of a satellite in circular orbit?

Comment: To take a partial derivative with respect to $M$, treat anything which is not $M$ as constant. Also, the partial derivative operator with respect to $M$ is written $\frac{\partial}{\partial M}$, not $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}M}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\large{\frac{d}{dM} \frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{GM}}}$ means that you differentiate $\large{\frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{GM}}}$ with respect to $M$.

It is $\sqrt{GM}=\sqrt G \cdot \sqrt M=G^{1/2}\cdot M^{1/2}$. Therfore it is

$\large{\frac{d}{dM} \frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{G^{1/2}\cdot M^{1/2}}}=\large{\frac{d}{dM} \frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{G^{1/2}}}\cdot M^{ -1/2}$

You have to consider $\frac{4\pi r^{\frac{3}{2}}}{G^{1/2}}$ as a constant, because it doesn´t depend on the variable M. Let denote it as $C$.

It becomes $\frac{d}{dM} C\cdot M^{ -1/2}$.

$C$ can be written in front of $\frac{d}{dM}$:

$C\frac{d}{dM}  M^{ -1/2}$

Now calculate the derivative of $M^{ -1/2}$ w.r.t $M$ and multiply the result by $C$.